# Why AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to display camera image at display preview. My intention is to use two dispatch queues, one for display session queue  and another one is for image processing. So that I can display images on the preview and then in the background, I can do image processing. That is why I use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.

`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` is properly setup to link to AVCaptureSession for display at preview. But the delegate method

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

is never get called to retrieve the image and proceed for image processing. What could be wrong with my setting? The code is shown below.

```
#import "AVCamViewController.h"

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

#import "AVCamPreviewView.h"
#import "ImageProcessing.h"

static void * CapturingStillImageContext = &CapturingStillImageContext;
static void * RecordingContext = &RecordingContext;
static void * SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext = &SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext;

@interface AVCamViewController() <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

// For use in the storyboards.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cpuButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *gpuButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet AVCamPreviewView *previewView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *cameraButton;
- (IBAction)changeCamera:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)focusAndExposeTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer;

// Session management.
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue; // Communicate with the session and other session objects on this queue.
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput;
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *vid_Output;


// Utilities.
@property (nonatomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundRecordingID;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isDeviceAuthorized) BOOL deviceAuthorized;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isSessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized) BOOL sessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL lockInterfaceRotation;
@property (nonatomic) id runtimeErrorHandlingObserver;
//fps
//@property int fps;

//Image processing management
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t im_processingQueue;
@property bool cpu_processing;
@property bool gpu_processing;

@end

@implementation AVCamViewController

- (BOOL)isSessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized
{
    return [[self session] isRunning] && [self isDeviceAuthorized];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"session.running", @"deviceAuthorized", nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // self.fps = 30;
    // Create the AVCaptureSession
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self setSession:session];

    // Setup the preview view
    [[self previewView] setSession:session];

    // Check for device authorization
    [self checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus];

    // In general it is not safe to mutate an AVCaptureSession or any of its inputs, outputs, or connections from multiple threads at the same time.
    // Why not do all of this on the main queue?
    // -[AVCaptureSession startRunning] is a blocking call which can take a long time. We dispatch session setup to the sessionQueue so that the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive).

    dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [self setSessionQueue:sessionQueue];



    //we will use a separate dispatch session not to block the main queue in processing
    dispatch_queue_t  im_processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("im_processing queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [self setIm_processingQueue:im_processingQueue];



    dispatch_async(sessionQueue, ^{
        [self setBackgroundRecordingID:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];

        NSError *error = nil;

        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCamViewController deviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferringPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];


        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        if ([session canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
        {
            [session addInput:videoDeviceInput];
            [self setVideoDeviceInput:videoDeviceInput];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Why are we dispatching this to the main queue?
                // Because AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is the backing layer for AVCamPreviewView and UIView can only be manipulated on main thread.
                // Note: As an exception to the above rule, it is not necessary to serialize video orientation changes on the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer’s connection with other session manipulation.

                [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)[self interfaceOrientation]];
            });
        }

        AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        if ([session canAddInput:audioDeviceInput])
        {
            [session addInput:audioDeviceInput];
        }

        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *vid_Output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        vid_Output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = NO;
        if ([session canAddOutput:vid_Output])
        {
            [session addOutput:vid_Output];
            AVCaptureConnection *connection = [vid_Output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            if ([connection isVideoStabilizationSupported])
                [connection setEnablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable:YES];
            [self setVid_Output:vid_Output];
        }


    });
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext];

        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"vid_Output.recording" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:RecordingContext];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(subjectAreaDidChange:) name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];

        __weak AVCamViewController *weakSelf = self;
        [self setRuntimeErrorHandlingObserver:[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification object:[self session] queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            AVCamViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
            dispatch_async([strongSelf sessionQueue], ^{
                // Manually restarting the session since it must have been stopped due to an error.
                [[strongSelf session] startRunning];

            });
        }]];
        [[self session] startRunning];
    });
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
        [[self session] stopRunning];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[self runtimeErrorHandlingObserver]];

        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized" context:SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext];

        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"vid_Output.recording" context:RecordingContext];
    });
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    // Disable autorotation of the interface when recording is in progress.
    return ![self lockInterfaceRotation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext)
    {
        BOOL isRunning = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (isRunning)
            {
                [[self cameraButton] setEnabled:YES];

            }
            else
            {
                [[self cameraButton] setEnabled:NO];

            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

#pragma mark Actions

- (IBAction)changeCamera:(id)sender {
    [[self cameraButton] setEnabled:NO];

    dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
        AVCaptureDevice *currentVideoDevice = [[self videoDeviceInput] device];
        AVCaptureDevicePosition preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified;
        AVCaptureDevicePosition currentPosition = [currentVideoDevice position];

        switch (currentPosition)
        {
            case AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
                break;
            case AVCaptureDevicePositionBack:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
                break;
            case AVCaptureDevicePositionFront:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
                break;
        }


        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCamViewController deviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferringPosition:preferredPosition];


        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:nil];

        [[self session] beginConfiguration];

        [[self session] removeInput:[self videoDeviceInput]];
        if ([[self session] canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:currentVideoDevice];

            [AVCamViewController setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:videoDevice];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(subjectAreaDidChange:) name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:videoDevice];

            [[self session] addInput:videoDeviceInput];
            [self setVideoDeviceInput:videoDeviceInput];
        }
        else
        {
            [[self session] addInput:[self videoDeviceInput]];
        }

        [[self session] commitConfiguration];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[self cameraButton] setEnabled:YES];
        });
    });

}


- (IBAction)focusAndExposeTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint devicePoint = [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:[gestureRecognizer view]]];
    [self focusWithMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus exposeWithMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose atDevicePoint:devicePoint monitorSubjectAreaChange:YES];
}

- (void)subjectAreaDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGPoint devicePoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
    [self focusWithMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus exposeWithMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure atDevicePoint:devicePoint monitorSubjectAreaChange:NO];
}


#pragma mark Device Configuration

- (void)focusWithMode:(AVCaptureFocusMode)focusMode exposeWithMode:(AVCaptureExposureMode)exposureMode atDevicePoint:(CGPoint)point monitorSubjectAreaChange:(BOOL)monitorSubjectAreaChange
{
    dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoDeviceInput] device];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] && [device isFocusModeSupported:focusMode])
            {
                [device setFocusMode:focusMode];
                [device setFocusPointOfInterest:point];
            }
            if ([device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] && [device isExposureModeSupported:exposureMode])
            {
                [device setExposureMode:exposureMode];
                [device setExposurePointOfInterest:point];
            }
            [device setSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled:monitorSubjectAreaChange];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    });
}

+ (void)setFlashMode:(AVCaptureFlashMode)flashMode forDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device
{
    if ([device hasFlash] && [device isFlashModeSupported:flashMode])
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            [device setFlashMode:flashMode];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }
}

+ (AVCaptureDevice *)deviceWithMediaType:(NSString *)mediaType preferringPosition:(AVCaptureDevicePosition)position
{
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:mediaType];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [devices firstObject];

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        if ([device position] == position)
        {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    return captureDevice;
}

#pragma mark UI
- (void)checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus
{
    NSString *mediaType = AVMediaTypeVideo;

    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:mediaType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted)
        {
            //Granted access to mediaType
            [self setDeviceAuthorized:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            //Not granted access to mediaType
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"AVCam!"
                                            message:@"AVCam doesn't have permission to use Camera, please change privacy settings"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                [self setDeviceAuthorized:NO];
            });
        }
    }];
}


- (IBAction)gpuButtonPress:(id)sender {
    self.cpu_processing = false;
    self.gpu_processing = true;
}

- (IBAction)cpuButtonPress:(id)sender {
        self.cpu_processing = true;
        self.gpu_processing = false;
}

- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    int frontCameraImageOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored;
    //int backCameraImageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage  imageWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:(CGFloat)1.0 orientation:frontCameraImageOrientation];
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}

#pragma mark File Output Delegate


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_async([self im_processingQueue], ^{
            UIImage *img = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

        });

        //To get back main thread for UI display
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Now I found the problem. I need to assign SampleBufferDelegate to self. I added this line [vid_Output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:im_processingQueue]; after initialisation AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *vid_Output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];. Then it works.